# Unable to receive uid from Agora.io event OnActiveSpeakerHandler on Unity

Tags: agora.io

`using agora_gaming_rtc;`

on Start I call 
 `mRtcEngine.EnableAudioVolumeIndication(500, 10);`

and then I use this for receiving the event (`private void OnActiveSpeakerHandler(uint uid)`)

```
private void OnActiveSpeakerHandler(uint uid){
    uidTalking = (int)uid;
    Debug.Log("Is talking: " + uid);
}
```

But it's not launching any time.

I tried other events and they are not working either.

Answer (score 1):

Did you register your call back function to the delegate?

```
mRtcEngine.OnActiveSpeakerHandler += OnActiveSpeakerHandler;
```